# Failed to install Delve for the lambda container on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, delve

I used the VS Code AWS Toolkit and SAM to create a basic SAM web app based on Go(I VS Code generate it).
It's some generic template code for the Lambda that reads IP from request and returns a `Hello <IP>` on the browser.

My end goal is to manage to see line by line debugging on my lambda function in VS Code.
There seem to be some default configurations in my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "sunflowers:HelloWorldFunction (go1.x)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/sunflowers/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "payload": {},
                "environmentVariables": {},
                "runtime": "go1.x"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "API sunflowers:HelloWorldFunction (go1.x)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "api",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/sunflowers/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "api": {
                "path": "/hello",
                "httpMethod": "GET",
                "payload": {
                    "json": {}
                }
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "go1.x"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However on clicking the "Start Debugging" button, I get that error that it can't install delve:

```
2022-08-03 21:20:46 [ERROR]: log level: info
2022-08-03 21:20:47 [INFO]: Retrieving AWS endpoint data
2022-08-03 21:20:47 [INFO]: OS: Darwin arm64 21.6.0
2022-08-03 21:20:47 [INFO]: Visual Studio Code extension host:  1.69.2
2022-08-03 21:20:47 [INFO]: AWS Toolkit:  1.46.0
2022-08-03 21:20:47 [INFO]: node: 16.13.2
2022-08-03 21:20:47 [INFO]: electron: 18.3.5
2022-08-03 21:21:49 [WARN]: SAM debug: missing AWS credentials (Toolkit is not connected)
2022-08-03 21:21:50 [INFO]: autoconnect: connected: 'profile:default'
2022-08-03 21:21:50 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/Users/varungawande/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode/debuggers/delve/install-1.9.0.sh ]
2022-08-03 21:21:50 [ERROR]: Failed to cross-compile Delve debugger: Error: spawn Unknown system error -8
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:718:9)
    at Function.l [as spawn] (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:27:9212)
    at /Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:1734:1495
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at cc.run (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:1734:1099)
    at AH (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2076:252)
    at _H (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2075:195)
    at E6.invokeConfig (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2082:5965)
    at E6.makeAndInvokeConfig (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2082:1314)
    at E6.resolveDebugConfigurationWithSubstitutedVariables (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2082:1202) {
  errno: -8,
  code: 'Unknown system error -8',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
2022-08-03 21:22:27 [INFO]: Command: (not started) [/Users/varungawande/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode/debuggers/delve/install-1.9.0.sh ]
2022-08-03 21:22:27 [ERROR]: Failed to cross-compile Delve debugger: Error: spawn Unknown system error -8
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:718:9)
    at Function.l [as spawn] (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:27:9212)
    at /Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:1734:1495
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at cc.run (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:1734:1099)
    at AH (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2076:252)
    at _H (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2075:195)
    at E6.invokeConfig (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2082:5965)
    at E6.makeAndInvokeConfig (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2082:1314)
    at E6.resolveDebugConfigurationWithSubstitutedVariables (/Users/varungawande/.vscode/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.46.0/dist/src/main.js:2082:1202) {
  errno: -8,
  code: 'Unknown system error -8',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
2022-08-03 21:25:49 [INFO]: telemetry: sent batch (size=5)
```

My lambda requires the architecture `amd64`, while my Mac has the M1 chip, so it has an architecture of `arm64`. Is the above error due to this architecture mismatch?
I tried running the lambda locally using docker and that worked(using `sam local start-api` and `sam local invoke`), but am not sure the above with work as smoothly when using a debugger.

Comment: Yes, looks like a system architecture mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is due to a bug in AWS Toolkit extension of VS Code.  It was fixed in AWS Toolkit [1.47](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1470-2022-08-06).

Comment: This is now fixed in latest AWS Toolkit.